# How to stop movement from moving multiple spaces when a directional key is pressed

Tags: xna

I am making a 15 piece puzzle game and having difficulty making my sprite move one tile at a time, when i initially press the left key the sprite moves once, but after that the sprite moves multiple tiles after i press the keys again, instead of moving one tile like it should. Eventually this also messes with the sprites and some of them disappear. The code that i use to determine movement is:

```
if (positionx16 - positionx1 == 200 && positiony16 == positiony1)
{
    canswapleft1 = true;
}

if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    if (positionx16 > 0 && canswapleft1 == true)
    {
        positionx16 += -widthoftile;
        positionx1 += widthoftile;
        canswapleft1 = false;
    }
}
```

The positionx16 is the X position of the player controlled tile, and the positionx1 referes to the X position of the 1st tile, this was repeated for each tile.

Answer (score -1):

if what you want is going somewhere once per key press, try this:

```
if (positionx16 - positionx1 == 200 && positiony16 == positiony1)
{
    canswapleft1 = true;
}

if (oldState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Left) && newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
{
    if (positionx16 > 0 && canswapleft1 == true)
    {
        positionx16 -= widthoftile; // use -= instead of += -x
        positionx1 += widthoftile;
        canswapleft1 = false;
        while(newState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        { // do Nothing
          // Just wait until release
          // but note that you wont be able to do anything else, even updating other 
          // stuff, so the player really needs to release the key.
        }
    }
}
```

this might not be efficient and can be not suitable for your game.

also i Don't see - on what you shared - that your oldState is set, do you have such a thing in your final code?

```
oldState = newState; // for example
```

Comment: It most probably is going to hang because `while` is not returning control to game framework.

Comment: This type of programming stuff works well on arduino so i was like ‘this could work’ but it might block the game for ever if the keyboard state is related to the update() funct but i don’t think it’s the case